# Clear Interactive Grid PopupLOV Search History

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

I have Interactive Grid with a column of type PopupLOV, when open the PopupLOV dialog and search and choose one then add another row and open PopupLOV again it gives me the last keyword that I had a search for the previous row. Can you tell me how can I clear search history? thanks in advance.

See the image :

[image: PopupLOV]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding dynamic action on column that have a "Popup LOV" on.
it clears the text but without refreshing the entire list.
you can simply add a new one
when

event: click

selection type : Column(s)

Region: your IG region

Column: IG COLUMN_NAME

then in true part add a set value action

set type : static Assignment

value : (keep it empty)

Selection Type : JQuery Selector

jQuery Selector: .a-PopupLOV-search
[image]

Comment: this action set search input value to null and doesn't refresh PopupLov.

Comment: I mentioned that "it clears the text but without refreshing the entire list".

Answer (score 0):

Add one more True action. Follow same steps except this time "jQuery Selector" will be ".a-PopupLOV-results"

Answer (score 0):

Clear the Popup LOV's cached search history (from the previous row of the interactive grid) using Cascading LOV.  Arbitrarily set the Popup LOV's Cascading LOV Parent Column attribute to any other column of the same grid (but not itself).

PS: There is no need to alter that column's main List of Values query to reference the Cascading LOV Parent Column.